# How can I generate a Word or PDF report in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to Generate a word or PDF report after executing Automation Script. So , Is there any Jar or any tools exist, to generate the word or pdf report?

Comment: Take a look at [Extent Reports](http://extentreports.com/) There's a community version and a pro version.  I don't know offhand if the community version has options to export the report in Word or PDF format, but it does report to HTML format.  Perhaps the pro version has that as a feature.  I know that the pro version has e-mail options, so it might have PDF as well.

Comment: I would suggest to write your own implemention to generate whatever report format you want using IReporter interface in TestNG.

Answer (score 1):

Would like to suggest you, to use Extent Report. Which is one of the most trending report framework.

There are many versions of Extent Report available, You can choose any as per your preferences.

Official Demos: http://extentreports.com/demo/

- ExtentHtmlReporter    Pro/Free
- ExtentLoggerReporter  Pro/Free
- ExtentAventReporter   Pro
- ExtentTabularReporter Pro
- ExtentEmailReporter   Pro
- ExtentCardsReporter   Pro
- ExtentBDDReporter     Pro
- ExtentKlovReporter    Pro/Free

This is one of the simplest [implementation](https://github.com/ishah09/ExtentReport-3.1.5/tree/master/src/test/java/extentReportDemos) of ExtentHTMLReport, with ease of use.